# How to make sense of this context-sensitive production in a textbook? (a typo perhaps?)

Tags: formal-grammars, context-sensitive

In Chapter 1 of Kenneth Slonneger and Barry L. Kurtz's [*Formal Syntax and Semantics of Programming Languages: A Laboratory Based Approach*](https://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/science_and_technology/artificial_intelligence/Formal%20Syntax%20and%20Semantics%20of%20Programming%20Languages%20-%20Kenneth%20Slonneger.pdf), an example of its production is given to illustrate the nature of context-sensitive grammar (page 3):

```
<thing> b ::= b <thing>
```

where `<thing>` is a non-terminal and `b` is a terminal.

I cannot see how this fits the form

$$αAβ → αγβ $$
<sub>(where $α$ and $β$ are strings, $A$ is a non-terminal and $γ$ is a non-empty string)</sub> for context-sensitive grammar unless the right hand side ends with $b$ as well:

```
<thing> b ::= b <thing> b
```

in which case we get $α=ε$, $β=b$ and $γ = b\; \text{<thing>}$.

Perhaps I haven't viewed it in the right angle? (Or is this a typo?)

Comment: Hint: $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are strings over *what*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, they describe [noncontracting grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar), and give an example: the one you are quoting.

Next, they write: *equivalently*, we can use a different restriction on grammars, and describe the [context-sensitive grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar).

Chomsky proved the [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(formal_languages)) in 1963.